# For loop in Python results in undesired outcome

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I was doing some EDA in Python with the [automobile data](https://www.kaggle.com/toramky/automobile-dataset) and wanted to check some basic stat analysis on grouped data. Here is the code,

```
df = pd.read_csv('Automobile_data1.csv')

for (make, symboling), sub_df in df.groupby(['make', 'symboling']):
    print("Make: {0}, Symboling: {1}".format(make, symboling))
    print(sub_df['price'].describe())
```

The above code works as desired ,however when I run the code with **make** and **fuel-type** it does not produce the fuel type (gas or diesel), here is the code,

```
for (make, df['fuel-type']), sub_df in df.groupby(['make', df['fuel-type']]):
    print("Make: {0}, Fuel Type: {1}".format(make, 'fuel-type'))
    print(sub_df['price'].describe())
```

Can you please help, I can't find out what mistakes I am making, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a literal 'fuel-type' in the second code snippet rather than the variable fuel_type which is always going to give 'fuel-type' for every iteration.

Comment: i tried with just fuel-type without quotes and it throws up error message 'name fuel not defined' and then I tried with df['fuel-type'] which does not throw up any error but produces some weird undesired outcome

Comment: Please create a MCVE so that we can reproduce the error. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When you do this part of the code:

```
print("Make: {0}, Fuel Type: {1}".format(make, 'fuel-type'))
```

You are always printing the **string** `fuel-type` inside the print statement. Your second code will not work as desired.

The first one looks fine and should work as expected.